# Grep number behind path, tab and space in a string

Tags: bash, shell, grep, regular-expression

Given a string s

```
s="B /home/BL/004_010_0100.0      23      0.031"
```

How can I grep only the number behind the path, tab and space in a string?

In the string s above, I'd like to extract the number 23.

```
num=$(echo $s | grep 'B .*\t (\d*)')
```

Comment: What can be assumed about the substring that looks like a pathname? Can it contain spaces and/or tabs?  Are the "fields" in the `$s` string delimited by spaces or tabs, or by some other character?  You mention a tab and a space, is that what's just in front of the number that you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to GNU `grep` (the default on Linux systems), this regex will capture digits without any decimal in them.

```
grep -oP '\b(?<!\.)\d+(?!\.)\b'
```

**regex Explanation:**

- `\b` matches a word boundary
- `(?<!\.)` Negative lookbehind to assert no decimal(`.`) is behind
- `\d+` matches a digit one or more times
- `(?!\.)` Negative lookahead asserts no decimal(`.`) is ahead
- `\b` matches a word boundary

Comment: @GeoRie But this will also match some **unrelated** things. Check it with `echo "AZAZA LOL      23      WTF" | grep -oP '\b(?<!\.)\d+(?!\.)\b'` - it returns `23`. So this is a bit **inaccurate solution**.

Comment: @narotello isn't it supposed to return `23`?

Comment: Yep, it's supposed. It is called false-positive error. The one who search the string with specified format (like starting from `B ` and so on) will find the value from wrong string.

Comment: If the pathname in the string contains spaces, this may possibly pick up numbers from it instead of from the end of the string.  It also assumes that there are no numbers earlier in the string (we don't know any variations of the data format though).

Comment: This would also extract `23` if the number was _actually_ `-23`.

Answer (score 4):

Treating the string as a set of whitespace-delimited fields, you want the second to last field:

```bsh
num=$( awk '{ print $(NF-1) }' <<<"$s" )
```

or, in shells without here-strings,

```bsh
num=$( printf '%s\n' "$s" | awk '{ print $(NF-1) }' )
```

This feeds the string in `$s` into an `awk` command.  The `awk` command outputs the second to last whitespace-delimited field.  This result is assigned to the `num` variable.

Testing:

```
$ s="B /home/BL/004_010_0100.0      23      0.031"
$ num=$( awk '{ print $(NF-1) }' <<<"$s" )
$ printf 'num is "%s"\n' "$num"
num is "23"
```

If your data in `$s` comes from a command, then you may feed that into `awk` directly instead of storing it in an intermediate variable:

```bsh
num=$( some-command | awk '{ print $(NF-1) }' )
```

---

`grep` is a tool that returns matching *lines* (ignoring the non-standard `-o` option available in some implementations of the tool).  We can use `grep` to pick out the number if we first transform the string `$s` into several lines based on the whitespaces in the string:

```
$ tr -s '[:blank:]' '[\n*]' <<<"$s" | grep -x '[[:digit:]]\{1,\}'
23
```

The `tr` command used here changes the string from

```
B /home/BL/004_010_0100.0      23      0.031
```

into

```
B
/home/BL/004_010_0100.0
23
0.031
```

and the `grep` command picks out the line that *only* consists of digits (the `-x` option would force the given pattern to match a complete line).  This woud obviously only work if the number that you're looking for is a positive integer.

If you knew that you'd be interested in the second to last "field", then you could have used `tail` and `head` instead:

```
$ tr -s '[:blank:]' '[\n*]' <<<"$s" | tail -n 2 | head -n 1
23
```

... or `sed`:

```
$ tr -s '[:blank:]' '[\n*]' <<<"$s" | sed -n -e '${ g; p; }' -e h
23
```

---

All the variations above are standard and portable. We can also use `cut` to extract the second to last field if we use the non-standard `rev` utility to reverse the line twice:

```
$ rev <<<"$s" | tr -s '[:blank:]' '[\t*]' | cut -f 2 | rev
23
```

Here, we also employ `tr` to replace all whitespace characters by tabs (and squeeze them into *single* tabs).  `cut` then simply extracts the second field before `rev` reverses the extracted data again.

Answer (score 4):

You can try it with Perl:

```
echo "$s" | perl -e 'for(<>){/B\s+.*?\s+(\d+)\s+/;print $1}'
```

Here we find the string with:

- `B` character
- followed by one or more space characters - `\s+`
- followed by all lazy characters before the first space character(s) - `.*?\s+`
- followed by our desired number - capture it in  capture group in parentheses `(\d+)` - it's saved in `$1` special variable
- followed by one or more space characters - `\s+`.

This regexp could be refined (e.g. with `^` and `$` operators to point out the start and the end of string).

[Read more](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Regexe.html) about regex.

Answer (score 0):

Just changed your `grep` a bit. If you are using GNU `grep` (the default on Linux systems), this should work:

```
s="B /home/BL/004_010_0100.0      23      0.031"
num=$(echo $s | grep -oP '\.*?\s+\d+\s+')
```

Comment: This will include the whitespace on either side of the number.

Comment: What good does the `\.*?` do? If I leave it out, this behaves the same. P.S. You should always use quotes when referencing shell variables; e.g., `echo "$s"` rather than `echo $s`.